# EXCEPTION: Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL / Angular2

Tags: json, http, angular

I am trying to get an http response in my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class CartService {
    constructor(private http: Http){ }

getCartItems() {
    return this.http.get('./cart/cart.json')
    .map(
        (res) => res.json()
      );
  }
}
```

But console shows EXCEPTION: Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL
[image]

My file tree (the **cart.json** file is in the **cart** folder root):
[image]

Found similar questions, but no answer worked to me.

**UPD** Moving the **cart.json** file into **public** folder and changing path to a shortened one solved the problem.

```
return this.http.get('../cart.json')
```

Comment: Why are you using an HTTP call to just get the content of a file elsewhere in the same application? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I am just learning, and was doing everything according to this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOp9OmNdHy4

Comment: I'd recommend running through the real tutorial, which shows how to move from a local file to actually needing HTTP https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to require something from a PATH, rather then a URL.  You need to make it accessible in your public folder.