# Getting error Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL

Tags: node.js, angular, http, neo4j, httpresponse

I am facing an issue while running the angular and nodejs app which I am trying to integrate with Neo4j app. The issues are the errors that I get-

```
POST http://localhost:7474/viewNodesStart 404 (Not Found)
```

and

```
EXCEPTION: Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: 
http://localhost:7474/viewNodesStart
```

Though this topic is repetitive in StackOverflow , I am still posting it because the following links suggestions didn't suit my issue.

[Angular2 404 Not Found for URL: http://localhost/WebApi2/api/hero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42321466/angular2-404-not-found-for-url-http-localhost-webapi2-api-hero)

[EXCEPTION: Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL / Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41989802/exception-response-with-status-404-not-found-for-url-angular2)

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-tour-of-heroes/issues/94

Please check my code

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { ToasterService } from '../toaster.service';

import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { config } from '../config';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

// Statics
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-neo4j-primary',
  templateUrl: './neo4j-primary.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./neo4j-primary.component.css']
})

export class Neo4jPrimaryComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: Http,  private notify: ToasterService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.viewNodesStart();
  }


  emptyObj;
  info;

  // -------------------------------  Nodes Entire Data --------------

   viewNodesStart() {

    console.log("INSIDE viewNodesStart()")

    // Nodes Value

    console.log("inside Nodes Value");
    var data = localStorage.getItem('token');

    console.log("data is=>",data);

    var url = config.url;
    var port = config.port;

    this.http.post("http://"+url+":"+port+"/viewNodesStart",this.emptyObj)
      .map(Response => Response.json())
      .subscribe((res: Response) => {

        console.log("XXXXXXXXXXXX Response on /viewNodesStart", res);

        this.info = res;

        console.log('success', this.info.statusCode);
        if (this.info.statusCode == 200) {
          this.notify.Success("Data added successfully");

        } else {
          this.notify.Error("Data is not inserted")
        }
      });

  }

}
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;

var app = express();
var restify = require('restify');
var expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
var session = require('express-session');
var config = require('./config.json')

app.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.json({
  type: 'application/vnd.api+json'
}))

app.use(cors());

app.use(session({
  secret: config.secret,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

//*****TM Server ******/

app.use('/viewNodesStart', require('./neo4jserver/tmserver'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Welcome');
  console.log("welcome in console");

});

// start server
var server = app.listen(7473, function() {
  console.log('Server listening at http://' + server.address().address + ':' + server.address().port);
});
```

**nodeserver.js**

```
// Require Neo4j
var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();
var app = express();

// Create Driver
const driver = new neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost:11001",neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "abc"));

// Run Cypher query
const cypher = 'MATCH (n) RETURN count(n) as count';

//View Engine

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

var session = driver.session();

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log("INSIDE NODE JS CONTROLLER OF viewNodesStart");
  console.log("BODY IS ", req.body);

  var log = JSON.parse(req.body);

  console.log(log);
  session.run('MATCH (n) RETURN n LIMIT 25').then(function(result) {
    result.records.forEach(function(record) {
      console.log("record", record);
      console.log("result = ", result)

      console.log("record._fields[0].properties", record._fields[0].properties);
      res.status(200).send({
        statusCode: '200',
        result: result
      });
    });
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }).then(res=>{
    console.log("res.records.length", res.records.length);
  }
  )
  res.send('It Works');
  res.send(result);

});

var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  if (req.method === "OPTIONS")
    res.send(200);
  else
    next();
}

console.log('Server started on port 11005');

module.exports = router;
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: can you show us the full url `console.log("http://"+url+":"+port+"/viewNodesStart")`

Comment: server.js and nodeserver.js which one you are using?

Comment: Its this - http://localhost:7474/#/neo4j-primary  (i run it in browser ). And the url in angular when decoded is --> http://localhost:7474/viewNodesStart

Comment: both ... server.js connects my node and angular counterpart . And nodeserver.js is my node controller file

Comment: what is the url in the browser? Angular path basically

Comment: localhost:7474/viewNodesStart  in my angular code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181544/discussion-between-exterminator-and-techdive).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with the url you are passing to the `http` request. You are passing the path of the anuglar route and want to call the node api.
Change the url there to the nodeapi url. Then it will work.